# How do I position my image such that it's in the centre of the slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics

What I'm trying to do over here is that I want to position my plot as shown in the second image below in the centre, covering the text behind it. However, after passing different position parameters in the square brackets, I'm still not able to position the plot in the centre. Could anyone help me out with this?

[image]

[image]

The following is the code I've used:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}  % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{frame}
\item We divided the procedure of solving the system of ODE into two main parts:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Estimating values for the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ using linear regression and the empirical data we have
\begin{itemize}
     \item Empirical data is provided in the form of an $n$-by-4 matrix with coefficients $(t,P,S,Q)$
\end{itemize}


    \item Finding the general solution to the system of ODE that accepts $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ as its parameters
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Remove independent variable $t$ from first two ODE to get a new ODE in terms of $P$ and $S$
            \item $\frac{dP}{dS} = \frac{P(-\alpha S -\gamma)}{S(\alpha P - (\beta + \gamma))}$
            \item Final equation: $\alpha (P+S) - \beta + \gamma \ln{\abs{P}} + \gamma \ln{\abs{S}} + C (*)$
            \item Next, by summing all three ODE, we get: $\frac{(P+S+Q)}{dt} = -\gamma (P+S+Q)$
            \item Integrating both side: $(P+S+Q) = K $e$^{-\gamma t} (**)$
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

    \pause 

    \begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=8cm]{one}
    \caption{Plot of $P(t)$, $S(t)$ and $Q(t)$ against $t$}
    \label{fig:3}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) OinkOink! Thank you for posting the beginning of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What's striking about the screenshot you've posted is that the frame contains *way too much information*. Moreover, the frame is missing one crucial bit of meta-information that's of vital information to the audience: a meaningful header line. Can you break up the material into three frames, maybe, and give each frame a meaningful, easy-to-grasp header?

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding that it's probably a bad idea (instead of drawing over an existing frame, why not make a new one?), you could abuse `tikz` for this (I used my own minimal document, but that shouldn't matter):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame Title}
        \begin{itemize}\item\lipsum[1]\end{itemize}
        %
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]